# Get session values with the same index tag and select the bigger int value

Tags: php

I have a session variable called `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"]` which saves an array formed by user defined selections on a web page (meaning: products, codes, prices, descriptions and number of active months).

The array will look something like `"Array => Array1["xxx"]=> ['product'] = "xxx", ['detail'] = "xxxxx", ['price'] = "xxx", ['envios'] = "x", Array2 => ......` and goes on. Now, SOME of the arrays in there will have an index `['envios'] = "x"` and some of them won't. This specific index is always an INT value between 1-12. I need to select all of the values with a index `['envios']` and then save the bigger one of them in a separated variable `$corval`.
Is there any way to do that?

I found several session functions as `session_search()` or `session_value()` BUT all of them will return the value of the index when the input is equal to some array value. And I need to do it the other way around.

Long story short, I need to get all the values for the index `['envios']` inside the session array and save only the bigger of them into a different variable in php. If there is no `['envios']` index the the variable will be equal to 1.

This is the actual array data:

```
Array ( [BTWL001] => Array ( [name] => P�lulas Winky Lux [code] => BTWL001 [price] => 95.00 [quantity] => 1 [stock] => 8 [image] => /bubale/img/productimg/set5winki.jpg ) [PB001] => 
                     Array ( [name] => BOLSINHA UNICA [code] => PB001 [price] => 130.00 [quantity] => 1 [stock] => 9999 [image] => /bubale/img/1month.png [envios] => 1 ) [PB003] => 
                     Array ( [name] => PLANO TRIMESTRAL [code] => PB003 [price] => 300.00 [quantity] => 1 [stock] => 9999 [image] => /bubale/img/3month.png [envios] => 3 ) [PB012] => 
                     Array ( [name] => PLANO ANUAL [code] => PB012 [price] => 1080.00 [quantity] => 1 [stock] => 9999 [image] => /bubale/img/12month.png [envios] => 12 ) )
```

Note that there are 3 arrays with the index tag ['envios']. This array is stored in a session so I need to get only those "['envios']" values.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the code you have tried that is not working as expected?

Comment: I've been looking for a solution but I have nothing yet, all the functions I know return the key value of an index according to the value of the array element (as I said).

Comment: I also tried to convert the array to string stating $session1 = strval($_SESSION['shopping_cart']; in the hope of strat working with a string but I get the error "Array to string convertion";.

Comment: It is not possible to determine anything here because what you have provided does not meet the requirements for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to read the help center, then [edit] your question, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: At the very least you need to provide the actual data you have as well as the expected result. Not as an explanation but as data.

Comment: I can print the session for you guys if it will help so you can see it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

well, after a lot of research I found a solution to this problem, so for those in search of something like this, here we go:

```
$col = $_SESSION['your session variable'];
$env = array_column($col, 'name of the index you need to extract');
```

// here the $env will have a new array with only the values identified with the index you looked up for) //

```
$final = max($env);
```

//you saved the maximum value of the array//

Comment: No one is commenting negatively just “for the fun of it”. This is supposed to be a Q&A site, that can possibly help future readers with similar problems. But that requires a clear & understandable problem description to begin with. Whether _you_, who are familiar with all the aspects of the problem and can go look up any missing information in your code/system, were finally able to solve this yourself, is really rather irrelevant in that regard. That is absolutely _not_ a valid measure for whether you asked what is considered a _good_ question by this community’s definition to begin with.

Comment: I understand, but the question is clear enough, and the solution works just fine. so If you ask me,the question was downvoted and the answer also downvoted as irrelevant being the real answer to the problem, and if the site point is to help others then a valid solution to a the question being down voted as not useful is kind of a joke really.

Comment: @EstebanLuques - It would be really awesome if you'd clarify the question so that this answer is clear.

Comment: The idea was to lookup for all the arrays with an existing index "envios" and then from THOSE select the biggest value for such index. (They have values between 1 and 12). I figured it out and put it there so anybody else can use it. It works.

Comment: @EstebanLuques - The question isn't clear to me so it reduces the value of the answer, regardless of if it works or not. The question should be made clear.